# Why do two users get different versions of the same binary?

Tags: python, aws

I have just updated a package using python-pip.  Two different users get different versions of the binary:

```
andrew$ which aws
/usr/bin/aws

andrew$ /usr/bin/aws  --version
aws-cli/1.16.194 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-1087-aws botocore/1.12.184

andrew$ sudo su tomcat

tomcat$ which aws
/usr/bin/aws

tomcat$ /usr/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-1087-aws botocore/1.4.70
```

That's happening within an application running as the tomcat user, as well as from the commandline.  I have upgraded from 1.11 to 1.16 today (using `pip3 install --upgrade pip awscli`), but the tomcat users still gets the old version. I've restarted the apache-tomcat server, logged out and in (although I haven't restarted the server).  Is it even possible for a program to be cached by linux for one user but not another?

Based on the comments, I believe that the two users have different environments which mean that when python imports awscli.clidriver it's a different version.  But how to find that out / fix it globally?
debian stretch/sid, x86_64

Comment: What was the command use for updating?

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/aws` is a binary at all? I suppose it's a `python` script and the user's environment may have a different path setting, so a different `aws-cli` is `import`ed. What does `set |grep -i python` return for both users?

Comment: excellent questions @Philippos.  You're right, it's a python script not a binary.  But as you can see from the output above, the python versions are the same but the botocore versions are different.  no reference to python in the output of set for either user.

Comment: What's different in the environment?

Comment: What was the command that was used to upgrade the module?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the command tha tinstalled the module - pip3 install --upgrade pip awscli

Comment: I know I am repeating myself, but what does `set |grep -i python` return for both users?

Comment: Most probably either different python installations or the difference in `sys.path`. Start with running ` python -c "import awscli; print('version:', awscli.__version__, 'root:', awscli.__file__)"` and `sudo -u tomcat python -c "import awscli; print('version:', awscli.__version__, 'root:', awscli.__file__)"` and inspecting the difference in paths.

Comment: `set | grep -i python` returns nothing for either user

Comment: Possibly because aws is just a stub, checking and something in your home directory, which is in different versions for different user. Check the stat of /usr/bin/aws under different user, it might be the same file.

Comment: thanks @hoefling.  After installing with sudo, `import awscli` reports "no module named awscli" no matter who I run it as, even though /usr/local/bin/aws imports it without error.

Answer (score 0):

This was a pip environment problem.  I don't really understand it because I'm sure the steps that solved it didn't work the first couple of times I tried them... But doing `sudo apt-get remove awscli` then `pip3 uninstall awscli` as both users then `sudo pip3 install awscli` finally installed it as I hoped.

After reading dozens of pip questions and answers all I know is that I don't understand how the various versions of pip interact with --user and sudo permissions.  I'm not going to mark my own answer as correct, but happy to consider any other answers.

Comment: Using sudo for pip would overwrite system  package provided files, do that only when you know what you're doing

Comment: Thanks  炸鱼薯条德里克 - that's why i'm not accepting my own answer! I don't really know what I'm doing, I only know that apt and pip --user both didn't do what i needed.